# Converting UTC format from server to local time and getting the time in HH:MM format

Tags: javascript, date

I'm converting the utc from the server to local time using javascript and it works.But I need only the time rather than the date+time.Without using moment.
server time(UTC format) : "2018-02-03T10:00:00"
converted local time :2018-02-03T04:30:00.000Z 
In the above local time I need only "04:30" alone .Is there any way to get it?

I tried the below one to convert from utc to local time

```
new Date(response.data.maxDate).toISOString();
```

Comment: you want as a string ?

Comment: yes I want it as a string.

Comment: please have a look at the referred answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

> Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString()
>   Returns a string with a locality sensitive representation of the time portion of this date based on system settings.

```
var time = datetime.toLocaleTimeString();
```

And if you want only hours:minutes then you can do this

```
date=new Date();
date.getHours() +':'+ date.getMinutes()
```

```js
    date=new Date();
    console.log(date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes());
```

Comment: It would better to reference the [*method page*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString), which has a better summary of the behaviour: "*The toLocaleTimeString() method returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the time portion of this date.*"